# Error while creating Aidl using Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

I am creating an AIDL in this way:

I set this 2 files in an AIDL directory:

IMDpcService.aidl:

```
// IMDpcService.aidl
package amiin.bazouk.application.com.doproject;

import amiin.bazouk.application.com.doproject.MBytes;

interface IMDpcService {

    void setResetPassword(MBytes bytes);
}
```

MBytes.aidl:

```
package amiin.bazouk.application.com.doproject;

parcelable MBytes;
```

I set these java classes in the java directory:

MDpcService.java:

```
package amiin.bazouk.application.com.doproject;

import android.app.Service;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

public class MDpcService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "Test-Tag";
    private Binder mBinder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mBinder = new MsiDpcServiceImpl(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    static class MDpcServiceImpl extends IMsiDpcService.Stub {

        private Context mContext;
        private DevicePolicyManager mDpm;
        private ComponentName cpntName;

        public MDpcServiceImpl(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            cpntName = new ComponentName(context, DeviceOwnerReceiver.class);
        }

        @Override
        public setResetPassword(MBytes bytes){
            //do sth
        }
    }
}
```

MBytes.java

```
package amiin.bazouk.application.com.doproject;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MBytes implements Parcelable {
    private byte[] _byte;

    public MBytes() {
    }

    public MBytes(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }


    public byte[] get_byte() {
        return _byte;
    }

    public void set_byte(byte[] _byte) {
        this._byte = _byte;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(_byte.length);
        dest.writeByteArray(_byte);
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        _byte = new byte[in.readInt()];
        in.readByteArray(_byte); 
    }

    public static final Creator CREATOR = new Creator() {
        public MBytes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MBytes(in);
        }

        public MBytes[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MBytes[size];
        }
    };

}
```

However, I am getting this error while compiling:

> Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw two issues in the source code, the following findings may help.

**1. At IMDpcService.aidl**:, You need to mention the directional tag(**in** or **out** or **inout**)
which indicating which way the data goes.

```
void setResetPassword(in MBytes bytes);
```

Description on Directional flags.

- in - object is transferred from client to service only used for inputs
- out - object is transferred from client to service only used
  for outputs.
- inout - object is transferred from client to service used for both inputs and outputs.

**2. At MBytes.java**, specify the type MBytes in CREATOR,

```
 public static final Creator<MBytes> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<MBytes>() {
        public MBytes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MBytes(in);
        }

        public MBytes[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MBytes[size];
        }
    };
```

Ref: [Directional tag explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700225/in-out-inout-in-a-aidl-interface-parameter-value)